# Open source GPS apps?

Tags: iphone, open-source, gps

Are there any full featured GPS applications available with source for the iPhone, preferably that use Open Street Map to get data? None of the current offerings work very well with Voiceover on the iPhone, but it'd be a lot easier to modify an existing app to work with Voiceover then write one from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excellent [route-me project](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/) is open source and uses Open Street Map (among other map providers). It includes a sample app, which I believe cannot be called full-featured but it should be pretty easy to extend it to something that matches most features of the built-in Maps app.

Answer (score 0):

[Sharp Map](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/)  is a geospatial application framework for .Net.  Not sure if anybody has tried it on the iPhone.

Might be possible to get running using [mono touch](http://monotouch.net/)